# How do you install xText via zip file in eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse, xtext

I'm looking to install xText in eclipse helios by downloading the zip file. Unfortunately, I cannot find instructions on how to install the plugin in eclipse after downloading. Does anyone know how I can install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to download any zip, Eclipse will do all the work. Just go on "HELP -> install new software..." and select this link

http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/tmf/updates/releases

in the "work with:" field.

Then just check the TMF Xtext-1.0.2 Helios option and follow the instructions

Comment: I'm behind a proxy, so I can't install via that way.

Comment: Installing the packet manually would be expensive, try to set a proxy on Eclipse, check this out http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/how-to-configure-proxy-settings-in-eclipse/

Comment: I want to add the xtext plugins to My existing eclipse plugins, I have downloaded the xtext zip file,After extracting xtext zip file, I copied the xtext plugins to the eclipse plugin folder, The eclipse is not providing Xtext nature. do you guys have any idea on this..please help me.. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

For next readers:

- in the menu go to "help -->install new software";
- in the dialogue window that appears click on "add" button, then a new small window appear;
- click on archive and browse to the location of your "xtext.zip" file (don't unzip it) then features will show on the first dialogue window, check them all and click "ok". It will install and ask of restarting eclipse;
- after reinitialization and to make sure it was installed,in the menu again, go to "file-->new-->project--xtext -->xtext project"  and a new tab containing hello word will show. Congratulations.